# Cyclic App Screens?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

Is there a way to make the "App-screens" cyclic, e.g. if you have four to be able to swipe from the 4th to the 1st one?

How to activate it?

Comment: Its definitely possible, Samsung's TouchWiz interface does this.

Comment: Great! I want it in my Huawei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) from the play store. You can import your old home screen pretty easily and it allows you to "infinite scroll".

Press `Menu` on the home screen > Press `Nova Settings` > Press `Desktop` > Check `Infinite Scroll`

Comment: :( you beat me by 3 mins

Comment: Thanx for the advice! Is it possible to implement this on other launchers? Playing with the code, scripts and stuff like that?